# implement hybrid rendering with D3D11

Tags: direct3d

How to implement a hybrid rendering using D3D11? suppose there are many draw calls for rendering one frame. Can we render some functions using CPU and other functions using GPU? thanks~

Comment: By "CPU" rendering you mean something like WARP or do you mean something like using an Intel Integrated part and a discrete GPU at the same time?

Comment: thanks for your reply. Suppose to render one frame we need to submit several rendering functions running on GPU. Here I mean can we run a subset of the rendering functions on CPU instead.

Comment: Beyond treating the WARP software device as another part of a multi-GPU setup, there's no support for this. Almost all such rendering is done with one frame per GPU, although if you have some method to composite the result you could try that.

Comment: thanks for the reply. According to my understand, to render one frame, there are several draw functions to be submitted. I know each draw function will go through the entire pipeline and not easy to transfer from GPU to CPU, but can we render a subset of the draw functions on CPU?

Comment: V-Ray has implemented some hybrid rending techniques using both CPU and GPU, do you have any idea how they do that? thanks~